# Is there a way to store multiple matrices in a vector in octave?

Tags: octave

I am quite new to octave and have the following question:
In Mathematica, you can initialize a vector, say `t = {0,0,0}` and can use each entry of `t` to store a matrix of possibly different size. For instance you could set

```
t[[1]] = IdentityMatrix[3];
t[[2]] = IdentityMatrix[4];
t[[3]] = IdentityMatrix[5];
```

giving you a 'tensor' with different dimensions for different first indices. Is there any equivalent way in Octave? My naive attempts failed.
I would like to use it in a neural network, where I need to reshape a long vector into several matrices depending on the number and size of the layers, which I would like to store in a vector for convenience of scalability.

Is this or something similar possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, have a look at cell arrays https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Cell-Arrays.html

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I am looking for! If you add it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [cell arrays](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Cell-Arrays.html) are for.

E.g.

```
t = { eye(3), eye(4), eye(5) }
```

gives

```
t =
{
  [1,1] =
Diagonal Matrix
     1   0   0
     0   1   0
     0   0   1
  [1,2] =
Diagonal Matrix
     1   0   0   0
     0   1   0   0
     0   0   1   0
     0   0   0   1
  [1,3] =
Diagonal Matrix
     1   0   0   0   0
     0   1   0   0   0
     0   0   1   0   0
     0   0   0   1   0
     0   0   0   0   1
}
```